# Why is Flask send_file() messing up the encoding

Tags: python, encoding, flask

I have a saved HTML file that I want to be able to open from my front end GUI.

The webpage has Japanese characters on it and has the following meta tag
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS" />`

If I drag and drop the file into any of Chrome, IE or Firefox, the page opens correctly. When I use a Flask to get the file however, the encoding is messed up and all japanese characters show up as the � symbol.

In my webapp I'm using a Flask route to get the file and send it to my front end. So in my front end I have the following tag

`<a href="/getFile/the_saved_file.html" target="_blank"></a>`

And in my Flask app I have the following route:

```
@app.route('/getFile/<file>/')
def get_file(file):
    file_path = os.path.join(FILE_STORAGE_PATH, file)
    return send_file(file_path)
```

When I click the `<a>` link, the file opens up in seperate tab.

How can I make Flask behave the same way as the drag and drop when it comes to preserving the encoding?

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but the problem is that `send_file()` auto-detects the content-type and supplies the header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. Once the charset has been defined in the headers, it can't be overridden by a  meta http-equiv.

Comment: What about trying to `open` and read the file contents, and then return `contents.encode('UTF-8')`?

Answer (score 0):

Override auto-detection of the content type by setting the mimetype parameter when you call send_file

```
return send_file(file_path, mimetype="Content-Type: text/html; charset=Shift_JIS")
```

Comment: so this works, but I want to see if I can defer charset decision to the browser. Not all my files are Shift_JIS.